# How to migrate index from Old Server to new server of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, kibana, reindex

I have one index in old elasticsearch server in 6.2.0 version (windows server) and now I am trying to move it to new server (Linux) on 7.6.2 version of elasticsearch. I tried below command to migrate my index from old to new server but it is throwing an exception.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://MyOldDNSName:9200"
    },
    "index": "test"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "test"
  }
}
```

Exception I am getting is -

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "[MyOldDNSName:9200] not whitelisted in reindex.remote.whitelist"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "[MyOldDNSName:9200] not whitelisted in reindex.remote.whitelist"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Note : I did not created any index in new elastic search server. do I have to create it with my old schema and then try to execute the above command ?

Comment: As per instruction I created the index in new server with old mappings. then I tried the same command. still getting same issue

Comment: any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite clear that your remote host(windows in your case) from which you are trying to build in a index on your new host(Linux) is not whitelisted, Please refer [Elasticsearch guide on how to reindex from remote](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote) on more info.

As per same doc

> Remote hosts have to be explicitly whitelisted in elasticsearch.yml
>   using the **reindex.remote.whitelist** property. It can be set to a
>   comma delimited list of allowed remote host and port combinations
>   (e.g. otherhost:9200, another:9200, 127.0.10.*:9200, localhost:*).

Another useful [discuss link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reindex-from-remote/78583) to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote

Add this to elasticsearch.yml, modify it according your environment:

```
reindex.remote.whitelist: "otherhost:9200, another:9200, 127.0.10.*:9200, localhost:*"
```

Answer (score 0):

In string error `"host": "http://MyOldDNSName:9200"`

Correct without http

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "MyOldDNSName:9200"
```